# Display the Sync Time b/w Primary and Secondary Port number in replica set in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

rs.printSlaveReplicationInfo()

This command in mongodb gives the sync or lag time between Primary and Secondary replica set,
But how to do this same in python

Answer (score 0):

```
from pymongo.mongo_replica_set_client import MongoReplicaSetClient
from pymongo import MongoClient
client=MongoClient
("mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27019/admin? 
replicaSet=xyz")
db = client['admin']
data = db.command({"replSetGetStatus": 1})
primary_optime = 0
secondary_optime = 0
for  key in data['members']:
    if key['stateStr'] == 'SECONDARY':
    #print(key['name'])
    secondary_optime = key['optimeDate']

    if key['stateStr'] == 'PRIMARY' :
     primary_optime = key['optimeDate']

print 'PrimaryOptime : '+str(primary_optime)
print 'SecondaryOptime : ' + str(secondary_optime)
seconds_lag = (primary_optime - secondary_optime ).total_seconds()
print 'secondary_lag : ' + str(seconds_lag)
```